# Draw discrete CDF in R

Tags: r

I want to draw a CDF in R, but I am having some problems. I want it to look like this:

[image]

But I get lines between the open and closed points by using the command `plot(x,y,type="s")`
So how do I get rid of those lines?

Comment: How doe you define the values on the y-axis?

Comment: `plot.ecdf` gets fairly close to what you want e.g. `x = rpois(42,5); plot(ecdf(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a general purpose example, but it will show you how to build the plot you desire in a couple of steps.

First, let's create some data (notice the zeros at the beginning):

```
x <- 0:6
fx <- c(0, 0.19, 0.21, 0.4, 0.12, 0.05, 0.03)

Fx <- cumsum(fx)
n <- length(x)
```

Then let's make an empty plot

```
plot(x = NA, y = NA, pch = NA, 
     xlim = c(0, max(x)), 
     ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "X label",
     ylab = "Y label",
     main = "Title")
```

Add closed circles, open circles, and finally the horizontal lines

```
points(x = x[-n], y = Fx[-1], pch=19)
points(x = x[-1], y = Fx[-1], pch=1)
for(i in 1:(n-1)) points(x=x[i+0:1], y=Fx[c(i,i)+1], type="l")
```

Viola!

[image]

---

If you insist on not seeing the line "inside" of the white points, do this instead:

```
points(x = x[-n], y = Fx[-1], pch=19)
for(i in 1:(n-1)) points(x=x[i+0:1], y=Fx[c(i,i)+1], type="l")
points(x = x[-1], y = Fx[-1], pch=19, col="white")
points(x = x[-1], y = Fx[-1], pch=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct this plot using:

```
plot(x, y, pch = 16, ylim = c(-0.03, 1.03), ylab = "CDF") # solid points/graphic settings
points(x[-1], y[-length(y)]) # open points
abline(h = c(0, 1), col = "grey", lty = 2) # horizontal lines
```

[image]

Note: `plot(x,y, type = "s)` does not produce a plot like your original question, but rather a step function with both treads (horizontal lines) *and* risers (vertical lines):

[image]

---

**Data**

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rpois(30, 3)) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(x) %>% 
  dplyr::add_count(x) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(x, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  mutate(y = cumsum(n) / sum(n)) 

x <- df$x
y <- df$y
```